# Global Inbox uses the API?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Just wondering if the GI uses the APIto work, it could but it would require a lot of requests (though it won't take up [internet] bandwidth because it's done inside the server cluster (that is hopefully the correct phrasing)

If I were to implement a similar feature using the API would I have to:

1. get all users account using
   stackauth.
2. Get users recent activity
3. check for activity on all the user's
   activity (lots of requests)

this sounds to heavy on the API, so possible to have an inbox in the API, like on stackauth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inbox does not use the API.

It can't be exposed until a subsequent version when user authentication is supported.

Comment: Why do we need user-authentication for that? Site-wise comments for Jon Skeet are already accessibly through API. And returning answers to his questions isn't much of security breach either (although, I'm more interested in comments). It seems, the difference would only be in reducing load of requests to SE.

Comment: @Nikita - some private things *do* go into the inbox.  They are quite rare, but they're there.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you have any changes planned regarding this (either for comments only, or for the whole inbox thing) or should I develop multiple queries solution for now?

Comment: @Nikita - no changes, the inbox won't be made available until authentication is added to the API.  Its too risky to try and filter out  "truly private" data from a feature that was assumed to be private from the start.  You should use multiple queries.