# Global Inbox **Unviewed Count** API

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Ok so some of the messages in the GI are private, those could be filtered out of the API return, or replaced by a type = private so that apps can let the user that if they want to see it they have to go to the site.

Or really what I wanted to ask in this edit is can we have access to the unread count:

http://stackexchange.com/inbox/genuwine/unviewed-count

except with a guid parameter to get the count for any user (in the same way you can get the order of the sites for any user, (the sites tab is ordered according to the rep of that user))

eg:
http://stackexchange.com/inbox/genuwine/unviewed-count?guid=c8039b19-c343-41eb-9ad8-31ff2f1cd3b3

the reason this would be useful is that it would make push notifications on iOS possible.

Comment: I don't know if this helps at all, but have you had a look at [/inbox](http://stackapps.com/inbox)?

Comment: yes It's great except it needs user authenitification/cookies on the site. So I'm pretty sure I can't use Apple Push Notification with it? (ie one server polling it every x minutes for many different users)

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this was answered in your [previous question](https://stackapps.com/questions/1705/global-inbox-uses-the-api) :)

*some private things do go into the inbox. They are quite rare, but they're there.*
Personally, I've never seen any of those 'private things', but I'm not [user 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) either.
Do admins use it to send ponies to each other?

Comment: Someone remembered that ;) Still not seen any of the private things, guess I'll have to stick to the /inbox. Annoying how I can't seem to get an answer about how to poll /inbox from a server.

Answer (score 1):

Chat notices from private rooms (mostly available to moderators) and careers messages go into the inbox.

These things are private, and will not be exposed prior to authentication.

I'm declining this as a request for authentication-less inbox access.

Comment: Can't all messages which are chat or careers be excluded by the API. Or just make the API only return type of comments and answers. I can't imagine it would be that hard to filter?