# Is there any API that provides an event mechanism to implement an outlook style alert when new responses are available for a user?

Tags: feature-request

I see that [Can we have some sort of notification system?](https://stackapps.com/questions/635/can-we-have-some-sort-of-notification-system) answers "NO" in no uncertain terms - I'm going to take a shot here because what I'm suggesting should not be any more complex than the logic it takes to maintain a browser session that makes the little number of messages appear in the StackExchange dropdown...

I think this could also be done with a scripted browser control, but it would be cleaner if one could simple say GET /user/notifications or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a valid session cookie for a given user, you actually *do* have access to the messages in the Stack Exchange dropdown using the following URL:

http://stackexchange.com/genuwine

This URL returns the user's most recent notifications across the network as JSON data.

Keep in mind that this would only be useful in a situation where you have access to a user's session cookie - such as in a browser extension or addon. Apparently [there is reason to hope that this will eventually be implemented](https://stackapps.com/questions/1705/global-inbox-uses-the-api/1706#1706) when the next version of the API rolls out.